# Page authentication not needed through browser, but needed from HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to access a page, https://www-banner.aub.edu.lb/pls/weba/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched, that from HtmlUnit. The page doesn't require any authentication when you access it from any browser, however, when you access it through code, it is redirecting my to the log in page! Any explanations and solutions?

This is my code:

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www-banner.aub.edu.lb/pls/weba/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.

    final HtmlForm form=page1.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='/pls/weba/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date']");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Submit");
    final HtmlHiddenInput field = form.getInputByName("p_calling_proc");

    // Change the value of the text field
    field.setValueAttribute("201350");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be that the server does not entirely trust your virtual browser (webclient) since it could be the case that the webclient does not provide all header information.

you might wanna take a look at [this other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336280/why-doesnt-htmlunit-work-on-this-https-webpage) if you haven't done so already. particularly, try to enable the use of insecure SSL. setting a  session cookie might be another possible solution